# jQuery ScrollTo & Chrome: Content flashes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slide

I am using the scrollTo jquery Plugin and the content flashes on every request to scroll

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/24A8V/1/

This happens only in Chrome.

Does anyone know why? It doesn't happen in the actual side of the plugin: http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

Comment: Why are you using the scrollto plugin? it's built into jquery.... the scrollto plugin was used years ago, before it was included into jquery. Check out the jquery API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because the anchor link makes the page scroll to the top of the page before the animation starts. You may prevent this default browser behaviour by adding the following within your handler:

```
$('.upp').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.scrollTo( '#up', 800 );
});
```